Getting a react hydration error when trying to iterate over an array in an element
I am trying to iterate over an array using MUI in a Next.js Application and I am getting a "hydration error".  The element has the following code:
'use client';
import { startTransition, useState } from 'react';
import {
  TextField,
  Button,
  Box,
  Paper,
  Select,
  MenuItem,
  FormControl,
  InputLabel,
  InputAdornment,
  Stack,
  Autocomplete,
} from '@mui/material';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import * as actions from '@/actions';
import ButtonSmall from '../UI/Button';
import SectionTitle from '../UI/SectionTitle';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';

export default function TransTest(props) {
  const OwnerArray = props.owners;
  const [transactions, setTransactions] = useState(props.property.transactions);
  console.log('transactions', transactions);
  return (
    <Box>
    {transactions.map((transactions) => (
    <Paper key={transactions._id}>
        <Box>
          <Typography variant='h6'>
            {transactions.closingDate}
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant='h6'>
            {transactions.salesPrice}
          </Typography>
        </Box> 
    </Paper>))}
    </Box>
    );
}

And this element is being imported inside of a "Box" element where "property" and "owners" are added as props.

Have you checked this? - https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error
